# Create new columns and filled with row data

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, dataframe

I want to summarize data for further analysis and would like to convert from single row to multiple rows with data refilled into 02 new columns.

[image: explanation]

I wonder if pandas can do this.

I would like to get some hints or solutions.

Comment: Are you looking for SQL Server experts to assist you? If not please remove the tag. And please don't use images for data... use formatted, tabular text.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try `.set_index()` + `.stack()`:

```py
df = (
    df.set_index(["Crew", "Forest", "HA"])
    .stack()
    .reset_index()
    .rename(columns={"level_3": "Date", 0: "Volume"})
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   Crew Forest    HA       Date  Volume
0    18   KANG  4794   3-Jul-23     290
1    18   KANG  4794  10-Jul-23    1120
2    18   KANG  4794  17-Jul-23     982
```

---

`df` used:

```
   Crew Forest    HA  3-Jul-23  10-Jul-23  17-Jul-23
0    18   KANG  4794       290       1120        982
```